# jQuery - hover on dynamically created element setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger an action after one second of hover (element is created dynamically), and if cursor is moved out I want to setTimeout = null;

```
$("nav").on("mouseover", ".dropDown ul li", function (ev) {
    var id = ev.target.id,
        timeoutId = null;
    $("#" + id).hover(function () {
        if (timeoutId === null) {
            timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
                timeoutId = null;
                alert(id);
            }, 1000);
        }
    },            
    function () {
        if (timeoutId !== null) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = null;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: A jsfiddle or some html code will be very helpful here.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Move your `timeoutId ` out of handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you are trying to register the dynamic hover handler is wrong, you can use event delegation with `mouseenter` and mouserleave events like

```
$("nav").on({
    mouseenter: function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log($this.attr('id'));
            $this.removeData('timeoutId');
        }, 1000);
        $this.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
    },
    mouseleave: function (ev) {
        var $this = $(this),
            timeoutId = $this.data('timeoutId');;
        $this.removeData('timeoutId');
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
}, ".dropDown ul li");
```

---

```js
$("nav").on({
  mouseenter: function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this);

    var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
      $this.removeData('timeoutId');

      //do your stuff here            
      console.log($this.attr('id'));

    }, 1000);
    $this.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
  },
  mouseleave: function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this),
      timeoutId = $this.data('timeoutId');;
    $this.removeData('timeoutId');
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
}, ".dropDown ul li");

//add more dynamic items
for (var i = 4; i < 7; i++) {
  $('<li />', {
    id: i,
    text: i
  }).appendTo('ul')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="dropDown">
    <ul>
      <li id="1">1</li>
      <li id="2">2</li>
      <li id="3">3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```